# Write Sendkeys commnad in @android for appium

Tags: appium, sendkeys

How can we write SendKeys command in Android by saying `@android`

```
MobileElement username  = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("com.devere.dcx:id/editTextemail");
username.sendKeys("shr@yopmail.com");
```

I want to write it as android command somethimg like this:

```
@ android findElementById("com.devere.dcx:id/editTextemail");
username.sendKeys("shr@yopmail.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Page Object model** if you want to access the element using annotation. Following is the sample of page object model.

```
public class Abcd {
    //you can access element using accessibility, id and xpath

    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "your cont-desc")
    private MobileElement textInput;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "your element's id")
    private MobileElement btn;

    public Abcd(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    public boolean inputEmail(String email) {
        textInput.sendkey(email)
    }
}
```

Now in your test class you can do

```
Abcd abcd=new Abcd(driver);
abcd.inputEmail("shr@yopmail.com");
```

> you must define your AppiumDriver as static